# Adding object to associated collection without yet saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a pair of models:

```
class Club < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :members, autosave: true
end

class Member < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :club
end
```

I would like to be able to add some new members to a club, without yet persisting the new members, until I save the club.  How could I do this?

Using `<<` to add a member to a club does not work as I want, since this automatically saves the member.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the has_many documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many), the "shovel" method `collection<<(object, …)`

> Adds one or more objects to the collection by setting their foreign keys to the collection's primary key. **Note that this operation instantly fires update SQL without waiting for the save or update call on the parent object**, unless the parent object is a new record.

If you want to construct a new-record without saving it to the database just yet, use `collection.build`.

> Returns one or more new objects of the collection type that have been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through a foreign key, but have not yet been saved.

Using Club and Member as example models:

```
club = Club.find(params[:id])
club.members.build(member_attributes) # member is not saved
club.save # saves club and members
```

Comment: if before save there would be another build `club.members.build(member_attributes2)`, would it create another association before save(total 2) or would it replace before created association ?

Comment: I believe that would create two records.

Comment: confirmed, yes it does. Is there way to ovverride `<<` to not run save like in scenerio where parent object is a new record

Comment: You probably would get some good answers and more visibility if you opened a new question. :)

Comment: That’s fine by me!

Answer (score 0):

Create an attribute called "temporar_id" for Member model.

The member is starts with temporary_id with club's id, but it is not associated with club yet.

`club_id` is `nil` until the `accept_members` is ran.

```rb
class Club < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :members, autosave: true

  # Accepts all new member, just as an example
  # Used like this in controller
  # @club = Club.find(params[:id])
  # @club.accept_members
  def accept_members
    User.find_all_by_temporary(true).each do |new_member|
      new_member.tempoary = false
      new_member.club_id = id 
    end
  end
end

class Member < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :temporary
  belongs_to :club
end
```

Answer (score -1):

What about this

```
def add_members
  @club = Club.find(params[:id])
  @members = #From_where_ever_you_want
  @members.each do |member|
  @club << member
end
end
```

until you call

```
@club.save
```

the new members are only stored in memory.

Comment: I don't see how that would work in my situation.  In line 3 you pull `@members` out of the database, but in my case they wouldn't be in the database.

Comment: Where are they? Do you have a array of names from a form?

Comment: They've been instantiated, in memory, but I can't see that it's important how.

Comment: Well then I guess you have'em stored in an instance variable. Just use this instead of my User.find. As long as you do not call @club.save it's only stored in memory. I have to say I really do not understand why you don't want to save it to the database. You can always delete the association and members later.

Comment: NB using the << operator causes an immediate SQL UPDATE, which is not what the OP was asking for.